# integrating facebook and twitter

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ipad, twitter

How to integrate facebook sharing and twitter sharing to iphone like posting some text or images on wall?I have tried twitter using the following code[enter link description here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/)

but it is not working?

Comment: Have you tried ShareKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For twitter use [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) and integrate in your application.

Change in Sharekit according to [this](http://jayrparro.posterous.com/incorrect-signature-sharekittwitter-error) link

Register for twitter API at https://dev.twitter.com// for client id and secret key

Now change SHKTwitterConsumerKey and SHKTwitterSecret to client id and secret key respectively in **SHKConfig.h**

For Facebook use [FBGraph API](http://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) link for sample code

Update: Please check https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/issues/4 if you find post to FB crashing while using code

Comment: I tried sharekit but getting like problem requesting authorization from twitter.

Comment: @Prince, while using Sharekit for Twitter, "Request error; There was a problem requesting authorization from twitter" ERROR shown. what to do?

Comment: read my answer again as u need to register first to use twitter API and change leys accordingly in sharekit.

Comment: @Prince, I replaced, SHKTwitterConsumerKey and SHKTwitterSecretkey, to my app keys,but an error shows,"Authorize error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found". whats my mistake,should I specify any callback url in SHKConfig.h

Comment: @Prince,replaced the callbackurl still getting "Authorize error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found". the tweetcomposecontroller pops up well and ask for login,it signs in well and asked to authorize the app, when I click to authorize, the above message was shown.Assist me where i'm lagging

Comment: fix your error from here : http://jayrparro.posterous.com/incorrect-signature-sharekittwitter-error

Answer (score 1):

If your app is only targeting devices with iOS 5 and above, you can use the inbuilt 'Twitter.framework'. More documentation can be found on Apple's website at this link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html

For Facebook, reading the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ is a good way to start; download the SDK and check out the sample app.